# Why does this simple assembly program work in AT&T syntax but not Intel syntax?

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, clang, x86-64

What's wrong with this code (Running on x86_64 Linux)?

```
.intel_syntax
.text
.globl _start

_start:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, msg
    mov rdx, 14
    syscall

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall

.data
msg:
    .ascii "Hello, world!\n"
```

When I run it:

```
$ clang -o hello_intel hello_intel.s  -nostdlib  && ./hello_intel
```

No output. Let's strace it:

```
$ strace ./hello_intel
execve("./hello_intel", ["./hello_intel"], [/* 96 vars */]) = 0
write(1, 0x77202c6f6c6c6548, 14)        = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
exit(0)                                 = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

It's dereferencing `msg` instead of using its location. Why?

If I use AT&T syntax instead...

```
.text
.globl _start

_start:
    mov $1, %rax
    mov $1, %rdi
    mov $msg, %rsi
    mov $14, %rdx
    syscall

    mov $60, %rax
    mov $0, %rdi
    syscall

.data
msg:
    .ascii "Hello, world!\n"
```

...it works fine:

```
$ clang -o hello_att hello_att.s  -nostdlib && ./hello_att
Hello, world!
```

What's the difference between these two?

Here's the working one:

```
$ objdump -d hello_att -s -M intel

hello_att:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .text:
 4000e8 48c7c001 00000048 c7c70100 000048c7  H......H......H.
 4000f8 c6160160 0048c7c2 0e000000 0f0548c7  ...`.H........H.
 400108 c03c0000 0048c7c7 00000000 0f05      .<...H........  
Contents of section .data:
 600116 48656c6c 6f2c2077 6f726c64 210a      Hello, world!.  

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000004000e8 <_start>:
  4000e8:   48 c7 c0 01 00 00 00    mov    rax,0x1
  4000ef:   48 c7 c7 01 00 00 00    mov    rdi,0x1
  4000f6:   48 c7 c6 16 01 60 00    mov    rsi,0x600116
  4000fd:   48 c7 c2 0e 00 00 00    mov    rdx,0xe
  400104:   0f 05                   syscall 
  400106:   48 c7 c0 3c 00 00 00    mov    rax,0x3c
  40010d:   48 c7 c7 00 00 00 00    mov    rdi,0x0
  400114:   0f 05                   syscall
```

And here's the broken one:

```
$ objdump -d hello_intel -s -M intel

hello_intel:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .text:
 4000e8 48c7c001 00000048 c7c70100 0000488b  H......H......H.
 4000f8 34251701 600048c7 c20e0000 000f0548  4%..`.H........H
 400108 c7c03c00 000048c7 c7000000 000f05    ..<...H........ 
Contents of section .data:
 600117 48656c6c 6f2c2077 6f726c64 210a      Hello, world!.  

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000004000e8 <_start>:
  4000e8:   48 c7 c0 01 00 00 00    mov    rax,0x1
  4000ef:   48 c7 c7 01 00 00 00    mov    rdi,0x1
  4000f6:   48 8b 34 25 17 01 60    mov    rsi,QWORD PTR ds:0x600117
  4000fd:   00 
  4000fe:   48 c7 c2 0e 00 00 00    mov    rdx,0xe
  400105:   0f 05                   syscall 
  400107:   48 c7 c0 3c 00 00 00    mov    rax,0x3c
  40010e:   48 c7 c7 00 00 00 00    mov    rdi,0x0
  400115:   0f 05                   syscall
```

So the important difference here is `0x600116` vs `QWORD PTR ds:0x600117`, which indeed looks like the difference between a pointer and dereferencing a pointer.

So how do you not dereference the pointer in the Intel syntax code?

Comment: I think you want intel without the prefix. replace `.intel_syntax` with `intel_syntax noprefix`

Comment: that makes clang and gcc have the same behavior, but does not solve the question

Comment: Sorry late here. In GNU assembler's Intel syntax you need to use the `offset` keyword `mov rsi, offset msg` to get the address of the label. Although maybe `clang` doesn't support that

Comment: looks like that's right, and it only works for gcc and not clang, and only if the noprefix is there. want to type up the answer or shall I do it?

Comment: You can type up an answer. One way around this in `clang` would be to use _LEA_ to do it. `lea rsi, [msg]`. Should work for both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's code that works in GCC:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.text
.globl _start

_start:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, offset msg
    mov rdx, 14
    syscall

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall

.data
msg:
    .ascii "Hello, world!\n"
```

Both the `noprefix` and the `offset` had to be added. Sadly this [does not work with clang](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32530):

```
hello_intel.s:8:24: error: unknown token in expression
    mov rsi, offset msg
                       ^
```

However, you can work around the issue by using `lea` instead of `mov`:

```
lea rsi, [msg+rip]
```

This works in both clang and gcc.  (And works in position-independent code).  It's the standard way to put static addresses in registers.

`mov esi, imm32` is a minor optimization over RIP-relative LEA for position-dependent, but `mov rsi, sign_extended_imm32` is the same code size as LEA.  It's apparently not possible in Clang's `.intel_syntax`, even though clang *emits* `offset msg` when compiling: [How to get `mov rdx, symbol` to move symbol value and not value at symbol's address in clang intel-syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58794762/how-to-get-mov-rdx-symbol-to-move-symbol-value-and-not-value-at-symbols-addr)

Comment: `LEA` 's making clear what's meant here  ... isn't our beloved MS's MASM assembling `mov eax, msg` into `mov eax, [msg]`? The confusion's perfect then :)

Comment: If you're going to use LEA in 64-bit mode for static addresses, always use RIP-relative instead of an absolute `disp32` addressing mode .  `lea rsi, msg[RIP]`.

Comment: This works in clang as of the LLVM 10.0 release. (I updated the bug linked above.)