# How to get `mov rdx, symbol` to move symbol value and not value at symbol's address in clang intel-syntax?

Tags: assembly, clang, x86-64, gnu-assembler, intel-syntax

I have the following code which I'm using with clang on macOS:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.data

hello:  .ascii  "Hello world\n"
hello_len = . - hello

.text

.globl  _main

_main:
        mov     rax, 0x2000004
        mov     rdi, 1
        lea     rsi, [rip + hello]
        mov     rdx, hello_len       # <-------
        syscall

        mov     rax, 0x2000001
        syscall
```

While it looks like it should print "Hello World" and exit, it actually segfaults.  It turns out it's because `mov rdx, hello_len` actually tries to move the value that is at address `hello_len`, not the value of `hello_len` itself.

If I used AT&T syntax, the line would be `movq $hello_len, %rdx` which works properly. What's the equivalent in clang's version of GAS intel syntax?

Comment: You should report this clang bug on https://bugs.llvm.org.  At least the fact it can't compile its own output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With real GAS (on Linux), your code assembles to a `mov rdx, sign_extended_imm32` like you want.

But yes, clang assembles it to `mov rdx, [0xc]` unfortunately.  That may or may not be a bug, but it's definitely an incompatibility.  (MacOS's `gcc` command is not the GNU Compiler Collection at all, it's Apple Clang: LLVM backend, clang frontend, absolutely nothing to do with the GNU project.)

**`OFFSET hello_len` doesn't seem to work**.  (I had incorrectly assumed it would on first guess, but clang doesn't support the OFFSET operator; it's `.intel_syntax` is not fully usable.)

This is [clang bug has already been reported](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32530).  See also [Why does this simple assembly program work in AT&T syntax but not Intel syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43223287/why-does-this-simple-assembly-program-work-in-att-syntax-but-not-intel-syntax)

---

**Clang can't even assemble its own `.intel_syntax noprefix` output.**
There may not be a way to get clang Intel syntax to use a symbol's value (address) as an immediate.

```
// hello.c
char hello[] = "abcdef";
char *foo() { return hello; }
```

`clang -S` prints `mov edi, offset hello` which won't assemble with clang's built-in assembler!  https://godbolt.org/z/x7vmm4.

```
$ clang -fno-pie -O1 -S -masm=intel hello.c
$ clang -c hello.s
hello.s:10:18: error: cannot use more than one symbol in memory operand
        mov     eax, offset hello
                            ^
$ clang --version
clang version 8.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_801/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
   ...
```

**IMO this is a bug, you should report it on clang's https://bugs.llvm.org**

(Linux non-PIE executables can take advantage of static addresses being in the low 32 bits of virtual address space by using `mov r32, imm32` instead of RIP-relative LEA.  And of course not `mov r64, imm64`.)

---

Workarounds: you can't just use the C preprocessor.  `. - hello` is context-sensitive; it has a different value when `.` is a different position.  So a text substitution wouldn't work.

#### Ugly Workaround: switch to `.att_syntax` and back:

Switch to `.att_syntax` and back for `mov $hello_len, %edx`

#### Ugly and inefficient workaround: `lea`

This won't work for 64-bit constants, but you can use `lea` to put a symbol address into a register.

Unfortunately clang/LLVM always uses a `disp32` addressing mode, even for register + small constant, when the small constant is a named symbol.  I guess it really is treating it like an address that might have a relocation.

Given this source:

```
##  your .rodata and  =  or .equ symbol definitions

_main:
        mov     eax, 0x2000004             # optimized from RAX
        mov     edi, 1
        lea     rsi, [rip + hello]
        mov     edx, hello_len             # load
        lea     edx, [hello_len]           # absolute disp32
        lea     edx, [rdi-1 + hello_len]   # reg + disp8 hopefully
#       mov     esi, offset hello          # clang chokes.
#        mov     rdx, OFFSET FLAT hello_len       # clang still chokes
.att_syntax
       lea    -1+hello_len(%rdi), %edx
       lea    -1+12(%rdi), %edx
       mov    $hello_len, %edx
.intel_syntax noprefix
        syscall

        mov     rax, 0x2000001
        syscall
```

clang assembles it to this machine code, as disassembled by `objdump -drwC -Mintel`.  Note that the LEA needs a ModRM + SIB to encode a 32-bit absolute addressing mode in 64-bit code.

```
   0:   b8 04 00 00 02          mov    eax,0x2000004       # efficient 5-byte mov r32, imm32
   5:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x1
                                                            # RIP-relative LEA
   a:   48 8d 35 00 00 00 00    lea    rsi,[rip+0x0]        # 11 <_main+0x11>   d: R_X86_64_PC32        .data-0x4

  11:   8b 14 25 0c 00 00 00    mov    edx,DWORD PTR ds:0xc   # the load we didn't want
  18:   8d 14 25 0c 00 00 00    lea    edx,ds:0xc             # LEA from the same [disp32] addressing mode.
  1f:   8d 97 0b 00 00 00       lea    edx,[rdi+0xb]          # [rdi+disp32] addressing mode, missed optimization to disp8
  25:   8d 97 0b 00 00 00       lea    edx,[rdi+0xb]          # AT&T lea    -1+hello_len(%rdi), %edx same problem
  2b:   8d 57 0b                lea    edx,[rdi+0xb]          # AT&T with lea hard-coded -1+12(%rdi)
  2e:   ba 0c 00 00 00          mov    edx,0xc                # AT&T mov    $hello_len, %edx

  33:   0f 05                   syscall 
  35:   48 c7 c0 01 00 00 02    mov    rax,0x2000001          # inefficient mov r64, sign_extended_imm32 from your source
  3c:   0f 05                   syscall
```

GAS assembling the same source makes `8d 57 0b  lea    edx,[rdi+0xb]` for the `lea     edx, [rdi-1 + hello_len]` version.

See https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code/132985#132985 - **LEA from a known-constant register is a win for code-size with nearby / small constants, and is actually fine for performance**.  (As long as the known-constant got that way without a dependency on a long chain of calculations).

But as you can see, clang fails to optimize that and still uses a reg+disp32 addressing mode even when the displacement would fit in a disp8.  It's still *slightly* better code-size than `[abs  disp32]` which requires a SIB byte; without a SIB byte that encoding means `[RIP + rel32]`.

Comment: Thanks for investigating, Peter. Actually taught me how to investigate this kind of thing as well. Sounds like I should either stick with nasm if I want Intel syntax or stick with AT&T if I want to use the GNU assembler or look-alike. Tending towards the latter as I'm interested in writing assembly for multiple platforms.

Comment: @Listerone: If real GAS is available on MacOS, making MachO64, you could use that.  But I think it might not be.  Be careful with NASM because it has had MachO64 bugs, and currently(?) still has one with 64-bit absolute addresses.  You should avoid those anyway (and use RIP-relative) but in general be careful.  [Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses. NASM Accessing Array](//stackoverflow.com/q/47300844) links to Q&As about both bugs.

Comment: @Listerone: NASM is portable to all mainstream x86 platforms.  But if you mean non-x86 then sure, GAS directives like `.byte` are the same there.  But other than instructions are is different anyway; I prefer the consistency of destination-first when using Intel-syntax on x86, or standard syntax on ARM/AArch64, MIPS, and most other ISAs.   (On x86 I prefer NASM to avoid any of the MASM-syntax crap that GAS .intel_syntax has; it's fine for read-only use but it's rarely used for actually writing asm.)

Comment: I would also like to write assembly for ARM with the Raspberry Pi. What's a recommended assembler for this?

Comment: @Listerone: GAS and clang both use the same syntax there.  The Keil assembler uses the same instruction syntax but different directives (like NASM-style `db` I think) but IDK if it's even freely available; I've never used it.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your opcode to:

```
lea rax, hello_len
```

it works.  In *old unix* as, =, or the more verbose .set, operated on lvalues. In this reality, hello_len is an address; specifically the address 12.

I can't recall *=* in masm syntax.  I recall *equ* serving a similar purpose, but it was all poorly specified.
We mainly used the *cpp* (and occasionally awk) to do the lifting for us, and avoided the asm features.

Comment: `=` and `.equ` are equivalent, AFAIK.  But yes, if you're willing to accept worse machine code, `lea` is a usable workaround for putting an absolute constant into a register.  It's good if you can do `lea eax, [rdi - 1 + hello_len]` to allow a more compact reg+disp32 or reg+disp8 addressing mode, given a known value of `1` in another register.